# Dont hide keyboard after pressing Submit in jQueryMobile / Mobile Safari

Tags: forms, webkit, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, usability

I am working on a mobile web based form for iOS/Android browsers. Everything works fine functionally.

What I can't seem to do is keep the keyboard on top AFTER the User presses the 'Submit' button on the form. Currently, as soon as I tap 'Submit' the keyboard hides by default. I have tried whatever I could think of before posting this request here.

My code:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false;">
             <input id='chat' type="text" name="message" value="" data-inline="true" placeholder="Start typing your message here" />
             <button id='doSend' type="submit" data-inline="true">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Am testing this with jQueryMobile 1.0 beta2 + iPhone 4.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding focus back to the '#chat' field on a callback / after your submit has completed.

```
$('#chat').focus();
```

Here is a demo I created that simulates the functionality (tested on iPhone)...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/hYn7k/1/

Comment: Thank you for your link, it works well in my mobile safari. Somehow I can't get mine to do that. On the chat client (chat.js) I tried to put the focus() call on every callback function that I found connected to the "send message" function. But nada!